# Variable que necesita ser declarada como final

Tags: java, android

Android Studio me suelta el siguiente problema:

> Error:(83, 25) error: local variable btArrayAdapter is accessed from
>   within inner class; needs to be declared final

Sin embargo si lo pongo fuera del evento del boton onclick se quita el error.

```
package net.stackblue_v1_0.stackblue_v1_0;

    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Set;


    public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        public final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        public Switch switch1;
        public Button buttonBD;
        public ListView listViewDE;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            buttonBD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBD);

            ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            listViewDE = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDE);



            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Su dispositivo no soporta bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switch1.setChecked(false);
            }

            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El servicio Bluetooth ya estaba activado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switch1.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                switch1.setChecked(true);
                }

            switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

                    } else {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    }
                }
            });


            buttonBD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                        // Loop through paired devices
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mas de un device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                            btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        }
                    }
                    listViewDE.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Barkalez. Actualmente, tu pregunta no pose ningún texto donde se explique cuál es el problema que tienes con este código. Por favor te recomiendo que la edites y agregues la información necesaria para comprender qué problema tienes y de preferencia muestra el código relevante del problema, no todo el código de la aplicación.

Comment: Es el primero y estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 3):

El problema parece estar en estas líneas de código:

```
buttonBD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mas de un device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                //aquí
                btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
        listViewDE.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
    }
});
```

Esto sucede porque la variable `btArrayAdapter` es una variable local al método `onCreate` tal como se muestra aquí:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* código previo */

    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    /* resto del código */
}
```

Estás utilizando esa variable local al método dentro de una clase interna que es local al método. Esto no está permitido en Java puesto que la clase interna podría reinicializar la instancia de esa variable. Para ello, se debe marcar la variable como tipo `final`, de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* código previo */

    final ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    /* resto del código */
}
```

Al marcar la variable como tipo `final`, el compilador puede detectar que esta variable sera inicializada solo cuando es declarada y no puede ser re inicializada después, asegurando que no sucede el problema de posiblemente reinicializar una variable local al método desde una clase local al método.

Ten en cuenta que esto no sucede con los campos de la clase, como `listViewDE`.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, genial, llevaba 2 horas con el fallo, creo que voy a tener que pasar mas tiempo por aquí, y además explicando la solución.

Comment: @Barkalez de nada. Este problema es más sobre conceptos de Java que sobre Android, quizás por ello te dificultó encontrar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comunmente se realiza es definir la variable a nivel de clase:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
```

dentro de `onCreate()` la inicializas:

```
btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

y puedes utilizarla dentro del `OnClickListener` de tu botón.

La otra opción es definirla como `final`, como te sugiere el mensaje

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```